# How do I read the checklists from Trello using python

Tags: python, trello

I am using python to retrieve certain cards from a Trello board. This is my code:

```
import trello
from trello import TrelloClient
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
import re
import pandas as pd

client = TrelloClient(
api_key=mykey,
api_secret=myapisecret,
token=mytoken)

start_date = '2019-10-23 09:00:00'
end_date = '2019-10-25 14:00:00'

date = []
description = []
tag = []
comment = []
card_name = []
username = []

all_boards = client.list_boards()
minutes_board = all_boards[1]

for lists in minutes_board.list_lists():
    my_list = minutes_board.get_list(lists.id)   
    for card in my_list.list_cards():
        for j in range(len(card.comments)):
            comment_date = parse(card.comments[j]['date']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            if comment_date >= start_date and comment_date <= end_date:
                text = card.comments[j]['data']['text']
```

On top of the card information, I want to get the standing items from a checklist and get the text. I tried the checklists method but I don't know how to read the properties from there.

I have tried:

```
for lists in minutes_board.list_lists():
    my_list = minutes_board.get_list(lists.id)   
    for card in my_list.list_cards():
        for cl in card.fetch_checklists():
            print(cl)
```

and cl looks like this:

```
<Checklist 5be2356788378207b77cf02a>
```

How can I access the info of the Checklist?

Thanks.

Comment: What's the error you're getting?

Comment: I'm not getting any error, I just don't know how to get the standing items on the checklists for each card.

Comment: what do you want your final result to be? a list of comments from each card from the chosen board or what?

Comment: an array (like the 'text' one) with the text of the standing items

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import trello
from trello import TrelloClient
import datetime
from dateutil.parser import parse
import re
import pandas as pd

client = TrelloClient(
api_key=mykey,
api_secret=myapisecret,
token=mytoken)

start_date = '2019-10-23 09:00:00'
end_date = '2019-10-25 14:00:00'

date = []
description = []
tag = []
comment = []
card_name = []
username = []

all_boards = client.list_boards()
minutes_board = all_boards[1]

for lists in minutes_board.list_lists():
    my_list = minutes_board.get_list(lists.id)   
    for card in my_list.list_cards():
        for cl in card.fetch_checklists():
            for k in len(cl)
                print(cl[k].items)
        for j in range(len(card.comments)):
            comment_date = parse(card.comments[j]['date']).strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
            if comment_date >= start_date and comment_date <= end_date:
                text = card.comments[j]['data']['text']
```

The code added is

```
for cl in card.fetch_checklists():
     for k in len(cl)
         print(cl[k].items)
```

`cl[k].items` is a list with the data such as 'name' (content of the check item). That's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a function that takes a Trello board object, like your `minutes_board` for example, and outputs a JSON-like object. I.e. a `dict` keyed by the names of your board lists, whose values are also dictionaries, representing a single card under their respective list. Each card is keyed by their card `id`, with 2 fields for its value: 1) the card's title/subject, and 2) a Python list containing all comments texts for that card.

```py
def get_comment_texts(tboard):
    board_content = {}
    for ls in tboard.list_lists():
        list_content = {}
        for card in ls.list_cards():
            card_info = {}
            cid = card.id
            card_info['title'] = card.name
            comments = card.fetch_comments()
            texts = []
            for c in comments:
                texts.append(c['data']['text'])
            card_info['comments'] = texts
            list_content[cid] = card_info
        board_content[ls.name] = list_content
    return board_content
```

You can then use something like Python's `pprint` module to display the return object for easier viewing.

Note: I didn't bother doing a filter on the creation date, which I believe you should be able to figure out on your own. But you if you need help with that, just let me know.